# select statement for views that start with a certain string

Tags: oracle

In `oracle` database I have some `VIEWS`.

For example:

```
view_1
view_2
view_3_1
view_3_2
view_3_3
view_4
view5
```

Now I want to get a list that contains view_1, view_2, and view_3_anything

`Expected output`

```
view_1
view_2
view_3_1
view_3_2
view_3_3
```

How can I achieve that

Comment: query the data dictionary, e.g. `dba_views`, and filter for `view_name in (...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  view_name
  from  all_views    -- or user_views or dba_views depending on requirement
  where view_name in ('VIEW_1', 'VIEW_2')
UNION ALL
select  view_name
  from  all_views
  where view_name like 'VIEW_3_%'
;
```

Of course, this can also be done without `UNION ALL`, but that would require conditions related by `OR` in the `WHERE` clause - so the index on `VIEW_NAME` couldn't be used. This would matter on a massive database, where performance may become unacceptable if the index can't be used. (Same with using regular expressions - any solution with regular expressions will prevent the use of the index on `VIEW_NAME`.)

Comment: I'd add the DBA_MVIEW if he is also interested in the materialized views ( depends on OP's requirements )

Answer (score 0):

For a regular expression that matches `^VIEW_[12]$` and `^VIEW_3`:

```
select * from user_views
where  regexp_like(view_name,'^VIEW_(([12]$)|3)')
order by 1;
```